# How to get time since MySQL database last edited in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to know the time since a table in my MySQL database was edited. Is there any way to do this in PHP? The only way I can think of is to get the update time, and compare it to the current time (which will be a little bothersome).

Comment: What do you mean by edited?  The schema?  Or when the rows changed?

Comment: Why would that be bothersome?

Comment: the simple why is to add created and updated field into your table. also add

Comment: @eggyal I sucked it up and wrote it. Wasn't as bad as I thought it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to add a `timestamp` field, that is automatically updated whenever a row is changed.
Then you can find the last change time by selecting the last update value:

```
# Add a timestamp column:
ALTER TABLE [TABLENAME] add column `ts_update` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

# Get the last update value:
SELECT MAX(ts_update) from [TABLENAME];
```

Comment: And, in answer to the question, obtain time since last update with `SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(), MAX(ts_update)) FROM ...`.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME, UPDATE_TIME)
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a pain since `SHOW TABLE STATUS` doesn't seem to return a standard result set. Every way I tried to use it as a subquery failed. It seems like you'll need to figure it out programmatically.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS
WHERE name = 'target_table';
```

And if you're concerned about the timezone just do a separate `SELECT NOW()` to get the time the mysql server has.

Note: This will only show you the time at which the table schema was updated. If you want to know when the last time a row was inserted/edited you'll have to add a timestamp column like Amirshk suggested.

Comment: You can use [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/tables-table.html): see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13025133).

Comment: Nice. I knew there was a table I could just select from, but I thought it was in the 'mysql' db to which most users don't have access.

Comment: It's quite possible that "most users" won't have access to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` either, especially in a shared hosting environment.

Comment: Depends how locked-down it is. I'm blocked from `mysql` on my shared provider, but `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` still works.